# I can't find an error of the code. minesweeper C

Tags: c, minesweeper

I'm trying to make when I put some numbers in scan, and if there's mine(*), print boom and if there's no mine, print the number of mines near to it. I can't find a problem with the code, but there's an error. Please verify it if you find the problem.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10

int main (void)
{
    char minefield [N][N];
    int i, j;
    int k;
    int x, y;
    int count;
    int mine_number;

    count = 0;
    mine_number = N*N/10;

    srand((long)time(NULL));


    for (k=1; 0< k < mine_number; k=k+1) {
        i = rand() % N;
        j = rand() % N;
        minefield [i][j] = '*';
    }

    for (i=0; i < N; i=i+1) {
        for (j=0; j < N; j=j+1) {
            count = 0;
            if (minefield[i][j] != '*') {
                if (i == 0) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        if (minefield [i][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (j == N-1) {
                        if (minefield [i+1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        if (minefield [i][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if (i == N-1) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        if (minefield [i-1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (j == N-1) {
                        if (minefield [i-1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        if (minefield [i][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                else {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        if (minefield [i-1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (j == N-1) {
                        if (minefield [i-1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;

                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        if (minefield [i-1][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i-1][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j-1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        if (minefield [i+1][j+1] == '*') {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    if (minefield[x][y] = '*') {
        printf("boom");
    }

    else {
        printf("%d", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `0< k < mine_number` --> `k < mine_number` 2) `if (minefield[x][y] = '*') {` --> `if (minefield[x][y] == '*') {` 3) `else {
  printf("%d", count);
 }` ???

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. Clang, for example, emits: *"main.c:193:25: Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses"* on (2) in the above comment.

Comment: Note that you very likely end up placing fewer mines than you think, because you don't check whether you overwrite an existing mine. On the other hand, you might end up placing more mines than expected, because you don't initialise your `minefield`, which may have garbage asterisks already.

Comment: 4) You need put `minefield [i][j] = '0' + count;` at end of `if (minefield[i][j] != '*') { }` and `else { printf("%d", count); }` --> `else {
  printf("%c", minefield[x][y]);
 }`

Comment: It may be easier to initialise all fields to a count of zero and then increase the counts of adjacent cells when you place a mine.

Comment: thank you everybody. i'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are counting **before** you read the input, i.e. before you know what `x` and `y` is. In other words, currently you are counting "something" on the whole minefield which isn't what you want.

So the first thing to do is to read `x` and `y` before counting.

Further it seems to me that your big `if` statement is hard to read. You could reorganize it like:

```
if (scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) != 2 || x < 0 || x >= N || y < 0 || y >= N)
{
    // Illegal input
    exit(1);
}

if (minefield[x][y] == '*') {
    printf("boom");
}
else {
    count = 0;

    if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0) count += (minefield[x-1][y-1] == '*');
    if (x-1 >= 0) count += (minefield[x-1][y] == '*');
    ....
    .... Add code to cover all 8 combinations (i.e. add the 5 missing combinations)
    ....
    if (x+1 < N && y+1 < N) count += (minefield[x+1][y+1] == '*');

    printf("%d", count);
}
```